# CakePHP 3.5: Cannot access Plugin Classes after installing it via Composer

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

So I have a CakePHP 3 project and want to load [FluentDOM](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM), a PHP plugin not specifically written for CakePHP.
According to both software documentations, Composer is the way to go. In my understanding, all I would have to do is the following:

1. run `composer require fluentdom/fluentdom` in powershell
2. run `composer require fluentdom/selectors-phpcss` in powershell

**OR**

1. add the following to composer.json in the project's root directory:

`"require": {
    "fluentdom/fluentdom": "^7.0",
    "fluentdom/selectors-phpcss": "^1.1"
}`

2. run `composer update` in powershell

Both ways will install the desired plugins to *vendor/fluentdom/{pluginname}/* as expected, but */vendor/cakephp-plugins.php* won't include them, as implied by [CakePHP's plugin installation manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin-with-composer).

The following attempt to load either plugin in a controller by writing

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
Plugin::load('fluentdom/fluentdom');
Plugin::load('fluentdom/selectors-phpcss');
```

would cause an exception that the desired plugins were not found in *plugins/* :

> Make sure your plugin fluentdom/fluentdom is in the {absolute project path}\plugins\ directory and was loaded

-- Which is already odd, because Composer wouldn't install anything there to begin with.

I found that I might get around this issue by manually extending *vendor/cakephp-plugins.php* to include the correct paths:

```
'fluentdom/fluentdom' => $baseDir . '/vendor/fluentdom/fluentdom/',
'fluentdom/selectors-phpcss' => $baseDir . '/vendor/fluentdom/selectors-phpcss/'
```

(However, that doesn't seem the way to go, because this file is auto-generated and overwritten by Composer after every update.)

And even then, the final issue still persists: although the plugins seem to be loaded successfully (confirmed by running [`Plugin::loaded()`](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/wiki/CSS-Selectors#selectors-api)), I'd finally get the following exception when trying to access FluentDOM's classes [as described in their wiki](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/wiki/CSS-Selectors#selectors-api):

`$document = new FluentDOM\DOM\Document();`

> Class 'App\Controller\FluentDOM\DOM\Document' not found

Does the plugin miss out on having its' autoload executed?

Even extending the line in my controller to `Plugin::load('fluentdom/fluentdom', ['autoload' => true]);`, but doesn't seem to help either; [according to CakePHP's doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes), that shouldn't be necessary anyway.

So what am I missing?

Comment: When the CakePHP docs refer to plugins, they are only talking about CakePHP plugins. What you have is what they would call [vendor files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! First of all, I had the false presumption that Plugins and Vendor Packages are more or less the same: they are not; thanks to Greg Schmidt for pointing this out in the question's comments.

The issue was in the line of how I tried to access FluentDOM's class. While

`$document = new FluentDOM\DOM\Document();`

worked in a standalone php file, it didn't within the Cake project; I was missing a backslash:

`$document = new \FluentDOM\DOM\Document();`

**So, the entire path of actions to load a Vendor Package is merely:**

1. run `composer require fluentdom/fluentdom` in powershell
2. run `composer require fluentdom/selectors-phpcss` in powershell
3. Use the new classes right away with `$document = new \FluentDOM\DOM\Document();`

No further steps required. Side note: Composer seems to refresh autoload config after installing a vendor file with `composer require {vendor}/{package}`, but in case it doesn't, or autoload config is messed up from earlier experiments, `composer dumpautoload` should fix it.